# Why this error is coming TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: redux, react-redux

How to solve this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined.
I am very new to react-redux and redux, simply I am trying to do state management through redux.
For this I installed react-redux and redux npm packages. And I created a store, In store a have reducer.js file. Even I imported Provider and store in index.js. Help to resolve this issue.

In store folder I have reducer.js file

This is reducer.js file code

```
const initialState =  {
    age: 21
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {state};


    if(action.type === 'AGE_UP') {
        newState.age++
    }

    if(action.type === 'AGE_DOWN') {
        newState.age--
    }
    return newState;
};

export default reducer
```

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div>Age: <span>{this.props.age}</span></div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onAgeUp}>Age UP</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.onAgeDown}>Age Down</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    age:state.age
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onAgeUp: () => dispatch({type: 'AGE_UP'}),
    onAgeDown: () => dispatch({type: 'AGE_DOWN'})
  }
}
// export default connect()(App)
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps) (App)
```

This is index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reducer from './store/reducer';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore({}, reducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider projectStore={store}><App></App></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: use ```action={}``` on your reducer function parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see multiple issues in your code:

1. `createStore` takes reducer as the first argument, look at [API documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore), try this:

```js
const store = createStore(reducer);
```

2. `Provider` has prop `store` and not `projectStore`, look at [API documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider#provider), try this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App></App></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

3. You probably mutate your state in a reducer, try this:

```js
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    // it is better to use switch instead of if in reducer, for sake of readability
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'AGE_UP':
            // it is better to have return statement here, it is more robust to developer errors
            // it is better to use object spread and return result here than creating `newState` variable, you will do less errors
            return {...state, age: state.age + 1}
        case 'AGE_DOWN':
            return {...state, age: state.age - 1}
    }
    return state;
};
```